# how to add contents of a parent class method into a subclass method

Tags: python, oop

Okay I'm new to OOP, and my problem is that I have this parent class and it has a method info in it.I want to reuse the two print statements within that method for its subclass inside a method of the same name and add more information to it. but I can't get it to work

```
class company:

    def __init__(self, fName, lName, salary):

        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
        self.salary = salary

    def info(self):
        print("Name:", self.fName, self.lName)
        print("Salary:", self.salary)

class programmers(company):
    def __init__(self, fName, lName, salary, progLang):

        super().__init__(fName, lName, salary)
        self.progLang = progLang

    def info(self):
        print("Programming language:", self.progLang)

programmer1 = programmers("John", "Doe", 1000, "Python")
programmer1.info()
```

I thought of just rewriting the lines of code I want to reuse but I though that would take the point out of OOP.

I'm looking for this kind of output...

```
Name: John Doe
Salary: 1000
Programming language: Python
```

I'm using Python 3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `super` is your friend: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/01/21/python-201-what-is-super/

Comment: You should describe what you tried that "didn't work"

Comment: I want to take the two print statements in the parent class info method and add more info to it on the programmers class info method

Comment: Mmm... In your model, a 'programer' IS_A 'company' How is it possible?

Comment: Then you must use the appropriate relation. For example, your 'company' could have a list of programmers. And each programmer, have another list, for the companies where he works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out below code. Your parent class should inherit from `"object"`. super only works for [new style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)

```
class company(object):

    def __init__(self, fName, lName, salary):

        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
        self.salary = salary

    def info(self):
        print("Name:", self.fName, self.lName)
        print("Salary:", self.salary)

class programmers(company):
    def __init__(self, fName, lName, salary, progLang):

        super(programmers, self).__init__(fName, lName, salary)
        self.progLang = progLang

    def info(self):
        super(programmers, self).info()
        print("Programming language:", self.progLang)

programmer1 = programmers("John", "Doe", 1000, "Python")
programmer1.info()
```

Comment: I did as you said but i received an attributeError

Comment: In Python 3, you don't need to pass those arguments to `super`, nor do you need to inherit from `object`, that happens by default (only "new style" classes)

Comment: @acubal However, this still *should* work. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @jaunpa.arrivillaga : That is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @acubal: Actual problem with your code was missing inheritance from object.

Comment: @Akshay No, not it is Python 3. All classes are new-style, there are no old-style classes in Python 3.

Comment: @jaunpa.arrivillaga: You made right point but generally porting between Python 2.7 and 3 becomes hard because of legacy code and I still prefer to go by things which are supported in both. :) Just posting a link out of interest to understand further. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#subclass-object
but of course if given a choice, going with new things will be always better.

Comment: @Akshay I actually agree with what you say, and I always explicitly subclass from `object`, but it isn't the cause of whatever error OP is encountering. That is simply my point.

Comment: @Akshay, thank you very much it works now : )